# Editing CSV files with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My CSV file contains `""` which ruins the file, when I import using Pandas, it considers that all columns as one value.

what I want to make is to change the following value in the column

`4.7,3.2,1.3,.2,"Setosa"`

to

`4.7,3.2,1.3,.2,'Setosa'`

Comment: please, show your code. Also, do You use `quoting`, `sep` parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like below?

```
string.replace('"', "'")
```